# Regularity requirements for Green's identity

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

While working on regularity theory for variational formulation of PDEs I often find *Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ and $u$ be sufficiently regular so that Green's identity
$$      \int_\Omega (-\Delta u)v = \int_\Omega \nabla u\cdot \nabla v - \int_{\partial \Omega}v\, \partial_n u$$
holds*.

My question is: *How regular does $\Omega$ has to be so that the above statement holds for $u \in H^2 (\Omega)$*?

Thanks so much in advanced,

D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\partial\Omega$ and $u$ have to be smooth enough in order for the integral $\int_{\partial\Omega}v\partial_n u$ to make sense.

What suffices is: Lipschitz continuity for the boundary and $\partial_n u\in L^2(\partial\Omega)$, for $u$. Even with weaker assumptions it is OK, for example $\partial_n u\in H^{-1/2}(\partial\Omega)$.

Comment: The reference I had in mind (PDEs by Avner Friedman) is not reader friendly book. Let me check and see if I can find anything friendlier.

Comment: I looked but could not find references to regularity. I found the theory of adjoint equations, which amounts to the same thing, but it was all about smooth functions.

Comment: See *Theoretical Numerical Analysis: A Functional Analysis Framework* By Kendall Atkinson, Weimin Han - Chapter 8.

Comment: Found it. Thank you so much for your effort.